# How to send the result of a function to an inputText?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to send the result of the search made in the database to the inputsText.
But I don't know how to do that.
In the case that I have a search field, this field receives the value that must be searched in the database.
I would like to send the values ​​to the inputsText of my registration form.

**Controller:**

```
using FormularioAspNetMvc.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FormularioAspNetMvc.Controllers
{
    public class PessoasController : Controller
    {
        private CadastroContext db = new CadastroContext();
        public ActionResult Cadastro()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Buscar(string cpf, string busca = null)
        {
            string resultado = Convert.ToString(db.Pessoas.Where(resultado => resultado.CPF.Contains(busca)));
            cpf = resultado;
            return Content(cpf);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CadastrarPessoa(Pessoa pessoa)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Cadastro", pessoa);
            }

            db.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Sucesso");
        }

        public ActionResult Sucesso()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult ValidarCPF(string cpf)
        {
            var pessoa = db.Pessoas.Find(cpf);
            return Json(pessoa == null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FormularioAspNetMvc.Models
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        [Key]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CPF.")]
        [Remote("ValidarCPF", "Pessoas", ErrorMessage = "Esse CPF já foi cadastrado.")]
        public string CPF { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome completo.")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter até {1} caracteres.")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-mail Inválido!")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter até {1} caracteres.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }


}
```

**View**

```
@model FormularioAspNetMvc.Models.Pessoa
@{ Layout = null; }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CADASTRO RCB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/formulario.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>CADASTRO RCB</h1>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CadastrarPessoa", "Pessoas"))
        {
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>CADASTRAR DADOS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @name = "nome", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nome" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @name = "cpf", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "000.000.000-00", data_tipo = "cpf" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @name = "email", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E-mail" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>}
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>BUSCAR DADOS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @name="busca", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "000.000.000-00", data_tipo = "cpf" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/mascaras.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/validacao_ptbr.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, do you want an autocomplete to be made on the input based on the database?

Comment: Hi! Autocomplete is not required.